# MySQL : Max value of combined columns

Tags: mysql

I need to return the highest value of two combined columns.

```
SELECT id, max(points1 + points2) as points from schema.table;
```

I want it to combine the two columns BEFORE looking for the highest value.  What it seems to be doing is finding the highest value for points1, then the highest value for points2, and then combining them.

I hope that makes sense!

UPDATE WITH SAMPLE:

```
ID     Points1     Points2
1      100         200
2      80          30
3      40          400
```

What max(points1 + points2) seems to be returning is a value of 500.  What i'm hoping to see is a value of 440 -- which is the highest COMBINED value.  Hopefully that makes more sense...

Comment: In one row, there is only one value for `points1` and `points2` each, so there is only one sum as well. Sounds to me like you want a `WHERE` clause instead...

Comment: Your query is not functional as it is.Show some sample data and the desired results,also you might want to take a look http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Zak answer is the correct one.

Comment: max(points1 + points2) is working as you expect, but the id you get is just the id of the first row

Comment: I've updated to include a sample data set and fixed the original query.

Comment: I've tried with your data and I get 440 (mysql 5.7, fields as INT): http://i.imgur.com/fXD5n9Z.png

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your post correctly, you are looking for:

```
SELECT id FROM schema.table
WHERE points1 + points2 = (SELECT MAX(points1 + points2) FROM schema.table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a pretty straightforward query:

```
SELECT id, point 
FROM schema.table
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(points1 + points2) as point
  FROM schema.table) q ON q.point=(points1+points2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
SELECT id, points1+points2 AS point FROM table ORDER BY point DESC LIMIT 1
```

without the `LIMIT 1`, you can get the full standings